# Convert string to datetime in specific timezone

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime, time, zone

I'm using datetimepicker and need to save the string datetime obtained from params to a datetime in a specific, user dependent time zone. It will allow me to save proper UTC datetime to database.

```
params[:notify_at] #=> "2014-07-05 14:30:00"

user.time_zone #=> #<ActiveSupport::TimeZone:0x00000007535ac8 @name="Warsaw", @utc_offset=nil, @tzinfo=#<TZInfo::TimezoneProxy: Europe/Warsaw>, @current_period=nil>
```

And I would like to do something like:

```
date = params[:notify_at].to_datetime(user.time_zone) #=> Sat, 05 Jul 2014 12:30:00 +0000
(its 14:30 in user's localtime but 12:30 in UTC)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the [in_time_zone](http://apidock.com/rails/DateTime/in_time_zone) method. For example:

```
DateTime.current.in_time_zone("Alaska")
# => Fri, 23 May 2014 07:21:30 AKDT -08:00
```

So for your use case:

```
params[:notify_at].to_datetime.in_time_zone(user.time_zone)
```

Pro Tip: If using Rails v4+ you can actually do this directly on the string:

```
"2014-07-05 14:30:00".in_time_zone("Alaska")
# => Sat, 05 Jul 2014 14:30:00 AKDT -08:00
```

**UPDATE**

You can parse a string directly into a time zone (where the String should already be IN that time zone) like this:

```
Time.zone.parse("2014-07-05 14:30:00")
# => Sat, 05 Jul 2014 14:30:00 CEST +02:00
```

So for your use case do:

```
user.time_zone.parse(params[:notify_at])
```

Comment: Already tried it this way but that's not what I mean to do. to_datetime converts string to UTC as it (so it would be 14:30 in UTC anyway). After calling in_time_zone('Warsaw') it gives me `Sat, 05 Jul 2014 16:30:00 CEST +02:00` which is wrong - I need `Sat, 05 Jul 2014 14:30:00 CEST +02:00`.

Comment: Yep that's it, just figured it out myself as well but thanks for the right answer :)

Answer (score -1):

Try this:-

```
date = params[:notify_at].to_datetime.in_time_zone(user.time_zone)
```

Rails console output:-

```
1.9.3p385 :004 > d= "2014-07-05 14:30:00"
=> "2014-07-05 14:30:00" 
1.9.3p385 :010 > d.to_datetime.in_time_zone("Pacific Time (US & Canada)")
=> Sat, 05 Jul 2014 07:30:00 PDT -07:00 
1.9.3p385 :011 > d.to_datetime.in_time_zone("Alaska")
=> Sat, 05 Jul 2014 06:30:00 AKDT -08:00 
1.9.3p385 :012 > to_datetime.in_time_zone
```